# Highcharts - How to combine unique legend for multi-series pie chart which perform same action for both series? (like onclick: show/hide)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Background info**: I am trying to create a multi series pie chart and want to avoid duplication of legends and on click of legend perform action for both series.

[Reference image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPCSa.png)

**Demo link**: https://jsfiddle.net/akd01/37jbLkgs/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
       marginTop:-30,
       marginBottom:90,
       height:300,
       type:'pie'
    },
    title:{
        text:''
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            /*point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function() {
                      return false;
                    }
                }
            }*/
        },
        
    },
    colors: ['#55d8fe', '#fd8373', '#feda83','#a3a0fb', '#69F0AE', '#E1BEE7','#B2DFDB', '#C5E1A5', '#F8BBD0', '#E6EE9C', '#C6FF00', '#FFF176'],
    series: [{
        name: 'New Projects',
        // innerSize: '40%',
        size: '60%',
        showInLegend: true,
        data: [{name: "Digital 1", y: 5.25},
            {name: "Digital 2", y: 0},
            {name: "FW", y: 13.48},
            {name: "M-signal", y: 17.19},
            {name: "OPS", y: 1.52},
            {name: "Other", y: 12.4},
            {name: "S/W", y: 10.82},
            {name: "Systems", y: 11.3}
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function () {
            let per = this.point.percentage.toFixed(1)+'%';
            return this.point.percentage !=0?per:null;
            },
          distance: -30,
          shadow:false,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            color: '#555',
            textOutline:0
          }
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'Ref. Project',
        innerSize: '60%',
        size: '80%',
        showInLegend: true,
        data: [{name: "Digital 1", y: 6.17},
            {name: "Digital 2", y: 32.31},
            {name: "FW", y: 11.01},
            {name: "M-signal", y: 20.15},
            {name: "OPS", y: 1.06},
            {name: "Other", y: 13.12},
            {name: "S/W", y: 7.34},
            {name: "Systems", y: 8.84}],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function () {
            let per = this.point.percentage.toFixed(1)+'%';
            return this.point.percentage !=0?per:null;
            },
          distance: -15,
          shadow:false,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            color: '#555',
            textOutline:0
          }
        },
    }],
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        // verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 0,
        y:10,
        // layout: 'vertical',
        itemMarginTop:7,
        marginBottom:40,
        itemStyle: {
            fontSize:'12px',
            fontWeight: 'normal'
        },
        symbolHeight: 15,
        symbolWidth: 15,
        symbolRadius: 0,
        symbolPadding:10
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }    
});
```

**I have tried**

1. showInLegend: true/false for series

Any ideas how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should use `linkedTo` property, but it works only for series not for points. To add linking functionality for points, use the below plugin which links points from different series by name.

```
(function(H) {
    H.addEvent(H.Point, 'legendItemClick', function() {
        const legendPoint = this;

        this.series.chart.series.forEach(s => {
            if (s !== legendPoint.series) {
                const matchedPoint = s.points.find(p => p.name === legendPoint.name);

                if (matchedPoint) {
                    matchedPoint.setVisible();
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/styhx6do/

**API Refernece:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.linkedTo

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts